# Issue with CVXPY vector compared vs an array that has parameters inside

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I have a boolean vector called cvx_bwic or length N, for simplicity let's assume N=100.
Given the huge dimension of my problem (thousand of integer variables), I'm also trying to use the warm up feature.
Ideally, my goal would be to split N into 10 parts and have each subset being less than or equal to a parameter.
This is my first attempt:

```
cvx_bwic = cvx.Variable( 100, boolean=True) 
tot = cvx_bwic.shape[0] 
chunks = 10
interval_size = int(tot/chunks)
param_d = {}
        
start_idx = 0
end_idx = interval_size
for i in range(chunks):
            print("\n* Working on i = {},   start_idx = {},   end_idx = {},   cvx_bwic = {} ".format(i, start_idx, end_idx, cvx_bwic.shape))
            param_d['param'+str(i)] = cvx.Parameter( integer=True)
            param_d['param'+str(i)].value=0
            
            if start_idx == 0:
                arr_filter = np.concatenate( (np.array([param_d['param'+str(i)]]*interval_size),
                                              np.array([1]*(tot - interval_size))) , axis=0 )
                                                                         
            elif end_idx == cvx_bwic.shape[0]:
                arr_filter = np.concatenate( (np.array([1]*start_idx) , 
                                              np.array([param_d['param'+str(i)]]*interval_size),
                                              np.array([1]*(tot - interval_size- start_idx))  )  , axis=0 )
            else:
                arr_filter = np.concatenate( (np.array([1]*start_idx) , 
                                              np.array([param_d['param'+str(i)]]*interval_size),
                                              np.array([1]*(tot - interval_size- start_idx)))   , axis=0)
     
            arr_filter = arr_filter * 1.0
            conslist.append(eval("cvx_bwic <= arr_filter"))
            start_idx = start_idx + interval_size
            end_idx = end_idx + interval_size
```

As soon as the code executes "eval("cvx_bwic <= arr_filter")" python gives me the following error message: *** ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
My question for you though is the following:
is this the right way to try to control the 100 possible boolean variables using only 10 parameters?
Thanks

Comment: This is incomplete code without much context and therefore you probably will not find much help here. But something general: imho 99% of all cases where people use `eval`, they don't know what they are doing and probably miss out some python-basics. I never saw a use-case for this and did implement many many optimization models.

Comment: Thank you Sascha, I have a few hundreds constraints tested with eval, so on that part, trust me, I know what I'm doing. I'm just extremely confused on cvxpy and the documentation lacks of real examples.

Comment: I would keep `cvx_bwic <= arr_filter` outside the loop, and calculate `arr_filter` outside (i.e. before)  the model. This calculation does not involve CVXPY and is pure Python. Make sure it has the same size as `cvx_bwic`.